# Balls in a bucket

Tags: choice-modeling

I have 4,000 empty buckets and I randomly put one ball in 200 buckets, so there are 200 buckets with balls, and 3,800 without. I then randomly pick one bucket. The chances of picking a bucket with a ball in it is 200/4000 or 0.05.

If I pick three random buckets, the chances of picking three buckets each with a ball in it is (I think) (200/4000) * (199/3999) * (198/3998).

First, is that right?

And second (and this is my real question): If I do this 10 times (with a fresh set of 4000 buckets and balls) what are the chances that I will pick three balls at least once out of the ten tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is right. Now let $p=(200/4000) * (199/3999) * (198/3998)$. You have now Bernoulli experiment with $n=10$ repetitions and $p$ - probability of success. You can use now Bernoulli $B(n,p)$ distribution for your calculations.

Or, faster, you can calculate chance of 10 failures. This is $(1-p)^{10}$. So chance of picking three balls at least once is $1-(1-p)^{10}$.

Comment: This is perfect. Just what I was looking for.